# Permanently disabling Android Lock

Tags: android

I want to permanently disable the lock in Android screen. i.e  even after power reset, lock should not appear

Can I do this ?

Comment: This question would be bette suited for the Android site, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For permanently disable lock in Android screen.you need to extend `DeviceAdminReceiver` for adding your application in device administrator list and after that u need to use `KeyguardManager` for enable/desable lockscreen.

**Note** :`DeviceAdminReceiver` avaliable from Android 2.2

for more infromation see docs:

[Device Administration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)

[Make your application a device administrator](http://rootfs.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/android-make-your-application-a-device-administrator/)