# Preventing Lock screen when phone restarts, so app can run immediately

Tags: android

I've finally got a lot of my app working over the last few weeks. The app is supposed to run at bootup, which it does. But the Lock screen that appears, when the phone restarts (say after the battery running out), prevents that from happening.

What setting or code can i use to prevent the phone starting with Lock screen?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
//add permission to AndroidManifest.xml

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>

WakeLock wl;//in class

//in onCreate method initiate them
PowerManager pm=(PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
wl=pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "anything");

//in onResume() method get lock
wl.acquire();

//in onPause() method release lock
wl.release();
```

Comment: No, even if you take a wakelock, it does not unlock the screen.

Comment: he says that his application get run after bootup.so cant he get wakelock and prevent locking screen???

Comment: @sampathpremarathna The screen is automatically locked upon boot, regardless of wakelock.

Comment: Eric/Royston are right. I've used wakelock succsesfully to prevent the screen from locking etc while running. However when the phone runs out of batteries, and is then recharged, and then restarts - the lock screen happens. :-/

I'm going to try using the advice here now - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029086/permanently-disabling-android-lock